# Day/Month/Year date changed to Month/Day/Year in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, asp-classic, date-format, iis-8.5

I have an old Classic ASP application that was worked perfectly, recently it was moved to window server 2012 server with IIS 8.5, the problem is that I have a form to add record with Day/Month/Year format, when the date entered as 23/06/2015 in SQL will be added correctly as 23/06/2015 but when date entered as 01/06/2015 : 1st june 2015 in SQL will be added as 06/01/2015 Month/Day/Year which will be incorrect

I checked the location and date format for the server and it was dd/mm/yyyy, and the database didn't changed since the old server SQL 2008.
I searched the net and found the i need to change the IIS culture under GLOBALIZATION, but I don't know what to choose even if I chose my country still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: This might not be an IIS issue, it may well be an SQL Server issue. Have you checked the region used by SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to get into changing globalization and localization settings, the simple answer is to use the universal date input `YYYYMMDD` when inserting dates as strings.

**Update**
To expland on your comment: when changing the format of the date string in an insert/update query it does not change the format within the sql table itself.

e.g.

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = '20150716 10:22'
WHERE Id = 7489
```

When viewed displays the same as the other records in the table:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply, i already change the globalization of the application in iis but nothing happened, also the database already have a huge data changed the date input now will affect the data

Comment: The format is only changed for the insert statement, not within the database itself so your existing data will remain unchanged.

Comment: is there any other setting i can modify in iis server that will over come this issue instead of updating the insert and update function which will be my last option ?

Comment: A quick search online suggests that you need to set the default language of the user that you're using. One such link: http://sion-it.co.uk/tech/setting-sql-server-to-accept-date-in-ddmmyyyy-format/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/date-time-settings.htm

Add an entry into global.asa as below...

```
'When a session starts on the server the following code will be run
Sub Session_OnStart

     'Set the server locale
     Session.LCID = 2057

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes when nothing fix this problem (or a global solution could damage old scripts), A workaround that you could use is the convert function, to change the format in your stored procedure.

For Example:

```
select getdate() --prints 2018-10-05 12:24:43.597
select Convert(char(10),getdate(),103) --To force the date to be dd/mm/yyyy
```

And not leting the asp page to format the date, just print raw.